# Stochastics exam Exercise

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

The professor uploaded an exam to practice, but unfortunately I have no solutions.

Let U be a unifomly distributed random variable on $[0,1]$.

1) Let $X=-ln(U)$. Show that $X$ is distributed exponentially.

2) Compute $\mathbb{E}(\ln(U))$ and $Var(\ln(U))$

3) Let $U_1, U_2, ...$ be a sequence of independent random variables, all with the same distribution as $U$. We define $V_n=\Pi_{i=1}^n U_i$. Show that the sequence $V_n^{1/n}$ converges almost surely and compute its limit.

4) Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real valued random variables that converges in distribution to a random variable $X$. Prove: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then the sequence $(f(X_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges in distribution to $f(X)$.

5) Let $W_n = (e^nV_n)^{1/\sqrt{n}}$. Show using 4) that $W_n$ converges in distribution for $n\to\infty$ to a random variable W. Determine the distribution of $W$. 
Hint: Consider $X_n=\ln W_n$ and express $W_n$ as $W_n=\exp(X_n)$

What I did so far:

1) $\mathbb{E}(f(X))=\mathbb{E}(f(-\ln(U)))=\int_0^1f(-\ln(u))du$ using change of variables $-\ln(u)=x$ implies $u = e^{-x}$ thus $\int_0^1f(-\ln(u))du = \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-x}dx$. Hence $X$ is distributed $Exp(1)$

2) $\mathbb{E}(\ln(U))=\int_0^1 \ln(u)du=-1$ 
For the Variance we need $\mathbb{E}(\ln(U))^2)=\int_0^1\ln(u)^2=...=2.$ Hence $Var(\ln(U)) = 1.$

3) I tried using the definition of almost sure convergence

$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty} (V_n)^{1/n} = V)=1$

$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty} (U_1,...,U_n)^{1/n} = V)=1$ But the U_n have the same distribution
$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty} (U^n)^{1/n} = V)=1$

But this doesn't make much sense since the $n$'s cancel.

Answer (score 2):

3) Consider $-\log(V^{1/n}_n)$ and use the fact 1 and 7 in : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions

4) $X_n$ converges in law to $X$ means $\forall g$ continuous bounded, $E(g(X_n)) \to E(g(X))$. Now, if you pick a continuous function $f$, what can you say about $E(g(f(X_n)))$ ?

Comment: Regarding 3) I think I found a different solution: $-\ln(V_n^{1/n})=-\ln((U_1\cdot ... \cdot U_n)^{1/n})=-\frac{1}{n}(\ln(U_1\cdot ...\cdot U_n))=-\frac{1}{n}(\ln(U_1)+...+\ln(U_n))$ and with the law of large numbers this is $-\mathbb{E}(\ln(U))=--1=1$. Is that correct? And how did you know to consider $-\ln(V_n^{1/n})$??

Comment: Yes it is correct. Because you look at $V_n^{1/n} = e^{\frac{\log(V_n)}{n}}$ and $-\log(U)\sim Exp$.

Comment: We know that the composition of a continuous function and a continuous & bounded function is again a continuous and bounded function. The continuous mapping theorem tells us that $\mathbb{E}(g(f(X_n)))$ converges in distribution to $\mathbb{E}(g(f(X)))$. Therefore $f(X_n)$ must converge to $f(X)$.

Comment: That is correct !